# Почему не отрабатывает repr в классе BigRect

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это можно поправить ?

```
list = (50,100)

def chord(a):
    return math.sqrt(r*r - a*a)

def init_slice(y_beg, y_end):
    # upper chord
    x1_beg = x_c - chord(r - y_beg)
    a = (x1_beg, y_beg)
    x1_end = x_c + chord(r - y_beg)
    b = (x1_end, y_beg)
    # lower chord
    x2_beg = x_c - chord(r - y_end)
    c = (x2_beg, y_end)
    x2_end = x_c + chord(r - y_end)
    d = (x2_end, y_end)
    return a, b, c, d

def slicing_circle():
    y_beg = gap_up
    y_end = y_beg + list[0]
    while y_end < 2*r - gap_down:
        points = init_slice(y_beg, y_end)
        slice_instance = Slice(points)
        slices.append(slice_instance)
        # Go to next slice
        y_beg += list[0] + gap
        y_end = y_beg + list[0]

class Slice():

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.arr = points

    def getPoints(self):
        return self.arr

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(map(str, self.arr)) 

class BigRect(Slice):

    def print(self):
        print("arr:", self.arr)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(map(str, self.arr))

# Empty list
slices = []      
slicing_circle()

biger = BigRect(slices[0])
biger.print()

print("slicer:", slices[0])
print("biger:", biger)
```

Метод `print` прекрасно отрабатывает. Строка кода `biger.print()` выдаёт на консоль

```
arr: (251.44345399598956, 10)

(388.55654600401044, 10)

(161.25492133612457, 60)

(478.74507866387546, 60)`
```

Метод `repr` класса `Slice` также прекрасно работает. Строка кода `print("slicer:", slices[0])` выдаёт на консоль

```
slicer: (251.44345399598956, 10)

(388.55654600401044, 10)

(161.25492133612457, 60)

(478.74507866387546, 60).
```

Метод `repr` класса `BigRect` не работает. Строка кода `print("biger:", biger)` выдаёт на консоль

```
biger: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./slice_test.py", line 84, in <module>

    print("biger:", biger)

  File "./slice_test.py", line 74, in __repr__

    return '\n'.join(map(str, self.arr))

TypeError: 'Slice' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как у вас заполняется slices.

Comment: @ insolor, добавил функции при помощи которых список `slices` пополняется. Кажется проблема именно метода repr при наследовании. Если этот метод закомментить в унаследованном классе, то ошибка та же, ругается на repr базового класса.

Comment: Может всё дело в ключевом слове `self` ? Оно же показывает на текущий объект класса, то есть на объект класса `BigRect`, но поле `arr` находится в базовом классе `Slice`. Для проверки этого специально написал метод `print`, но он без каких-либо проблем отработал.

Comment: Я пока подробно не смотрел, но вот тут я вижу что вы передаете в объект один элемент, а внутри предполагается что там какой-то набор элементов: `biger = BigRect(slices[0])`

Comment: @Tim, нет, поле arr не "находится в Slice". Хотя BigRect и наследует `__init__` из родительского класса, но все атрибуты, созданные в этом методе, становятся собственными атрибутами объекта класса BigRect.

Comment: @Xander, спасибо, не знал.

Answer (score 2):

У вас какой-то сумбур в логике.

Смотрите сами:

1. `BigRect` унаследован от `Slice`, в том числе и `__init__`
2. При этом `__init__` ожидает один аргумент - список точек.
3. Но когда вы создаёте объект `BigRect`, вы передаёте ему вместо списка объект `Slice`:

   `biger = BigRect(slices[0])`

Естественно, что когда дальше код пытается работать с этим объектом, как со списком, он спотыкается.

Кажется, что проблемы можно избежать, если делать так:

```
biger = BigRect(slices[0].arr)
```

Но я не уверен, что это будет именно то, что вы хотите.

Comment: спасибо, вы правы! Всё заработало. Насчет сумбура в логике, задача такая просто. У меня есть окружность, нарезаю её слоями определенной высоты, между которыми имеется зазор `gap`, сверху и снизу от этой окружности надо срезать сегменты ещё (не знаю для чего, попросили, сделал) в коде это зазоры `gap_up` и `gap_down`. И решил эти слои объектами сделать. Далее значит, в этом слое надо взять максимально большой прямоугольник, т.е. слой будет суммой = сегмент слева + большой прямоугольник + сегмент справа.

Comment: А затем в каждую из трёх этих фигур надо максимально плотно (опять же с каким-то зазором `gap`) разместить прямоугольники заданных размеров. Пытался вначале в процедурном стиле написать, но начал плыть с этими координатами, решил на объектах попробовать. Насколько понимаю задача что-то вроде `задачи о ранце` определенной формы и на плоскости с какими-то условиями.